# Does edge TPU support 1D convolution?

Tags: google-coral, edge-tpu

I was interested in the google corral usb accelerator for a project
I looked it up and it says it supports CNN models, but does that include 1 dimensional CNN models?

Comment: Please see the list of supported operations at : https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#supported-operations

Answer (score 0):

It's techincally possible. TFLite (and by extension the EdgeTPU) doesn't directly suppord Conv1D. But if you compile a model with Conv1D, the TFLite compiler will change that to a Reshape->Conv2D->Reshape. Because these operations are all accelerated on the EdgeTPU, you'll be able to run Conv1D without a significant performance hit.